# AddressValidationError when calling an entrypoint with Taquito

Tags: taquito, dapps, parameter

I'm trying to call the Plenty Router with Taquito to swap from kUSD (Kolibri USD) to tzBTC via Plenty token. In this example, I'm sending 1 kUSD. I'm using arbitrary minimum output (I do not compute them yet) but as far as I understand this should not be blocking.

I get the following error : "'[exchangeAddress] Address is not valid: undefined', stack: 'AddressValidationError: [exchangeAddress]"

```
  const swapF = async () => {
    // My address
    const addressReceiver = "tz1d4649CmmMEzXBWzhTgTkFxy9ATNhb5HC3"
    // Plenty-KUSD swap
    const addressPlentyKusdSwap = "KT1UNBvCJXiwJY6tmHM7CJUVwNPew53XkSfh";
    // Plenty-tzBTC swap
    const addressPlentyTzbtcSwap = "KT1HaDP8fRW7kavK2beST7o4RvzuvZbn5VwV";
    // Plenty token
    const addressPlentyToken = "KT1GRSvLoikDsXujKgZPsGLX8k8VvR2Tq95b";
    // tzBTC token
    const addressTzbtcToken = "KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn";

    // KUSD token contract
    const addressKusd = "KT1K9gCRgaLRFKTErYt1wVxA3Frb9FjasjTV";
    const contractKusdToken = await Tezos.wallet.at(addressKusd);

    // Plenty Swap Router contract
    const addressPlentySwapRouter = "KT1MEVCrGRCsoERXf6ahNLC4ik6J2vRH7Mm6"
    const contractPlentySwapRouter = await Tezos.wallet.at(addressPlentySwapRouter);
    // tzBTC token contract
    const contractTzBtcToken = await Tezos.wallet.at(addressTzbtcToken);

    try {    
      const routerMap = new MichelsonMap();
      routerMap.set("0", [addressPlentyKusdSwap, 10, addressPlentyToken, 0]);
      routerMap.set("1", [addressPlentyTzbtcSwap, 10, addressTzbtcToken, 0]);

      const batch = Tezos.wallet
        .batch()
        .withContractCall(contractKusdToken.methods.transfer(
          addressReceiver,
          addressPlentySwapRouter,
          1
        ))
        .withContractCall(
          contractPlentySwapRouter.methods.routerSwap(
            routerMap,
            1e12,
            addressReceiver
          )
        );

      console.error(batch);
      const batchOp = await batch.send();
      await batchOp.confirmation();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
```

I'm modeling my call to what I see on TzKT for a similar transaction

```
 {
"Route": {
"0": {
"minimumOutput": "50009918356658060000",
"exchangeAddress": "KT1UNBvCJXiwJY6tmHM7CJUVwNPew53XkSfh",
"requiredTokenId": "0",
"requiredTokenAddress": "KT1GRSvLoikDsXujKgZPsGLX8k8VvR2Tq95b"
}
"1": {
"minimumOutput": "4880",
"exchangeAddress": "KT1HaDP8fRW7kavK2beST7o4RvzuvZbn5VwV",
"requiredTokenId": "0",
"requiredTokenAddress": "KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn"
}
}
"recipient": "tz1d4649CmmMEzXBWzhTgTkFxy9ATNhb5HC3",
"SwapAmount": "1000000000000000000"
}
```

The Michelson output when I interact with the contract on Better-Call.dev is

```
Pair
  { Elt 0
         (Pair (Pair "KT1UNBvCJXiwJY6tmHM7CJUVwNPew53XkSfh" 10)
               (Pair "KT1GRSvLoikDsXujKgZPsGLX8k8VvR2Tq95b" 0)) ;
    Elt 1
         (Pair (Pair "KT1HaDP8fRW7kavK2beST7o4RvzuvZbn5VwV" 10)
               (Pair "KT1PWx2mnDueood7fEmfbBDKx1D9BAnnXitn" 0)) }
  (Pair 1 "tz1d4649CmmMEzXBWzhTgTkFxy9ATNhb5HC3")
```

That's why I'm using a MichelsonMap for the route and flat parameters.

Why is my exchangeAddress read as invalid ?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is probably the order of the fields.

Try to pass an object as value instead:

```
routerMap.set("...", {
  exchangeAddress: ...,
  minimumOutput: ...,
  requiredTokenAddress: ...,
  requiredTokenId: ...,
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have the same error message like that. The order I find in the code is the one I use by the way (not sure if it is enough to confirm the order) : (pair %routerSwap
               (map %Route nat
                           (pair
                             (pair (address %exchangeAddress) (nat %minimumOutput))
                               (pair (address %requiredTokenAddress)
                                   (nat %requiredTokenId))))
               (pair (nat %SwapAmount) (address %recipient))) 
https://better-call.dev/mainnet/KT1MEVCrGRCsoERXf6ahNLC4ik6J2vRH7Mm6/code